# Launching web server interactively from script and sending data to client through raw_input

Tags: javascript, python, web-applications, d3.js

I have this simple command line program in which I can add users, add a credit card to a user and make that user pay someone else, display the users payments, etc... I'd like to go a step further and draw that model on a website using d3.js. I'd still like to keep it as a command line program, but as soon as I add a user, I'd like a local webpage to open and display the node of that user in the browser. If I add a credit card and pay someone else, using command line arguments, I want the changes in the model to reflect the changes on the website... I would then be able to see the graph representing my model in the browser. My problem is, I don't know how I would launch the server interactively from my script and send the data from raw_input (stdin) to the browser... Any ideas?